# JQuery's setInterval to stop delaying the initial load?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble getting this JQuery to load instantly the first time but then do a delayed 2000 ms refresh after the initial load?  This works to a point where it does the refreshing correctly but I would like it to instantly load the page on the first interval.

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");},2000);
  });
</script>
<div id="myDiv" class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: For future reference: `setInterval` is normal JavaScript. It has nothing to do with jQuery. The only things you are using jQuery for in this script is the DOM ready event listener (`$(function() { ... });`) and the AJAX request via `.load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");
    },2000);
});
```

If you want a cleaner one

```
$(function(){
    function load(){
        $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");
    }

    load();

    setInterval(load,2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function loadDiv(){
   $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");
}

$(function(){
    loadDiv();
    setTimeout( loadDiv, 2000);
});
```

---

*ignore the following initial answer, as it was meant to reload every two seconds..*

```
function loadDiv(){
   $("#myDiv").load("mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>");
   setTimeout( loadDiv, 2000);
}

$(loadDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#myDiv').delay(500).queue(function( nxt ) {
    $(this).load('mysql.php?dove=<?php echo $a; ?>');
    nxt();
});
```